# Compiling C++ files during runtime using Visual Studio compiler

Tags: visual-studio, dll, compilation

I'm trying figure out how to compile C++ code from an executable during runtime using Visual Studio compiler under Windows.

I'll be using Visual Studio IDE to build main project into an executable and use CreateProcess to compile other C++ files and create a DLL to later load/use/unload this DLL.

I understand that one way of doing this requires setting environment variables(mainly PATH, INCLUDE and LIB) and there's a .bat file called "vcvarsall.bat" which does this.

The part I'm stuck with is the argument(s) passed to this batch file. I see that first argument is the platform with some of the options being x86, amd64, arm, etc. But how do I programmatically figure out which one of these arguments I should be using considering main executable could've been built with any one of these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prepare a regular solutionfor this purpose, containing one project with a single file, and use it to compile your file easily.

Now, all you need is to reame your file to the file name in the project and compile a solution with command line. Alternatively, you can also edit the project and replace the existing filename with your file name.

To do so you need to resolve the environment variable %DevEnvDir% and run the folowing command with the platform name (x64, win32 etc.) and configuration name(Release or Debug)

like this:

```
%DevEnvDir%\devenv.com \path\to\yoursolution.sln /ReBuild "Release|x64"
```